# Angular 11 Applying border to a component

Tags: css, angular

I recently started learning Angular by doing a pet project.
In on of my components I use Angular's feature of conditionally applying classes to components based on the result of the predicate. Now the problem is that my click event fires and the .selected class is applied to the angular component, but when I try to change border color nothing happens. Strange thing is that I can apply some styles to that component by changing the content of the class.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF37Y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoAaw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `display: block` to the `.selected` class **or** add `:host { display: block }` in the .scss-file of your app-product-item.